# Postgres odbc connection not showing stored procedures

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, odbc, database-connection

I'm working on postgres database application in C#. I have a problem with ODBC connection(PostgreSQL ODBC driver 8.04.0200-1). It's not showing stored procedures in VS Server Explorer, while showing tables and views. I plan to use a stored procedure in Crystal Reports. I administer the database, so I tried to grant execute privilage on the stored procedure to the role, but that didn't help. 
Anyone can help what might be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't have stored procedures. It does have user-defined functions though. Does "VS Server Explorer" know how to display these? Have you turned logging on your ODBC connection / at the server to see what queries it's using to find them?

Comment: You mean logging in ODBC Setup in Control Panel? No, I didn't.